# No matching distribution found for lal

Tags: python, module, pip, package

I was trying to install module lal using pip in wsl. However, error messages popped out:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lal (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lal
```

PS I am using python 2.7.17

Comment: What `pip` command did you use?

Comment: I used ' pip install lal '

Comment: According to `pip search` there  is nothing called `lal`. May I ask you what is `lal`?

Comment: I think it should be a module. Because I was trying to run a code which includes the following: `import lal`

Comment: OK, try `pip install lalsuite`

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is solved.

Comment: Glad I could help! I've added the answer, it might be helpful for other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue was that the original poster was trying to install [lalsuite](https://git.ligo.org/lscsoft/lalsuite) using `pip install lal` which isn't the right command. So, the solution is to use the right command which is:

```
pip install lalsuite
```